# Print random array on one line: Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random, tostring

Working on building an array that can generate random integer values inside an array. It prints the random numbers but it prints it like this
[10][2][5][7][6][2][4][7][2][10][0]--->(down the side)--------> and want it to print like this [10,7,5,9,4,3,4,7,2,3]   (one line).

```
   public class ArrayLab
{
    //array instance variable
    private int[] array1 = new int[10];

    //array constructor
    public ArrayLab(int integer)
    {
        //class parameter = 10
        int[] array1 = new int[]{integer};

    }

    public void initialize()
    {
         //allow randomization of numbers inside the array field.

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1)); 
        //prints [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] which is ok

        System.out.println();
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            Random number = new Random(); 
            number.nextInt(10);
            int n = number.nextInt(11);
            int[] array1 = new int[]{n};

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
           //prints down the side. Want on one line?
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29.

Comment: Use `print()` instead of `println()` (print line).

Comment: Or just have a look at `System.out.print()` instead of `println()` to avoid the newline being put at the end.

Comment: Ah ok, just got in the habit of using "println" thanks.

Comment: Btw do you know what `int[] array1 = new int[]{integer};` and `int[] array1 = new int[]{n};` mean and what happen there? Looks like a programming error to me.

Comment: I believe the int[] array1 = new int[variable] give it the amount of spaces that it will store in memory. The int[] array = new int[]{integer} would make the value of whatever the first integer is to 10. Hmm maybe i need a value inside of that like this int[] array = new int[10] {integer}?

Comment: Well first of all: please read what "shadowing" is. You're doing that and I believe that you don't want to do that. And `int[] array = new int[]{integer}` creates an array of size 1 with the one element `integer`. That is why your output is `[..][..][..]...` instead of `[.., .., .., ..]`. `new int[10] {integer}` doesn't work in Java. Either provide the length or the initial values, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1)); 
//new output
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array1));
```

another way you can get this done is by using a for loop to iterate through the array in similar fashion

```
for( int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ){
    System.out.print(array1[i]+" ");
}
```

for the random numbers

```
Random ran = new Random();
for( int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ){
    int number = ran.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    //insert the maximum and min values for your generator
    array1[i] = number;
```

Comment: That makes it print like this [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] which is great! But how would I integrate the random numbers inside of this?